How large can the Krull dimension of the Rees algebra be?
Let $d$ be a natural number. How large can the Krull dimension of the Rees algebra $A[It]$ be, where $A$ is a commutative ring of Krull dimension $d$, and $I$ is an ideal of $A$.
Currently, I know the following results:

$\dim A[t]=2d+1$ is possible (A. Seidenberg, On the dimension theory of rings. II).
When $d=0$, I think that $\dim A[It]\le1$ holds. I could not find any reference, so I will give a sketch of the proof.


Let $P_0\subsetneq P_1\subsetneq P_2$ be prime ideals of $A[It]$, $f=a_mt^m+\cdots+a_0\in P_1-P_0$ and $g=b_nt^n+\cdots+b_0\in P_2-P_1$.
We will derive a contradiction by induction on $m+n$. Note that $P_0\cap A=P_1\cap A=P_2\cap A$ by $\dim A=0$.

If $m=0$ or $n=0$, then we get a contradiction.
If $n\ge m\ge1$, then there exists $h\in A[It]$ such that $\deg(a_m^{n-m+1}g-hf)<m$. We have $a_m^{n-m+1}g-hf\in P_2$. So $a_m^{n-m+1}g-hf\in P_1$ by the inductive hypothesis with $(f,g):=(f,a_m^{n-m+1}g-hf)$. So $a_m\in P_1\cap A\subseteq P_0$. Since $\dim A=0$, there exist $k\ge0$ and $x\in A$ such that $a_m^k=xa_m^{k+1}$. So $(a_mt^m)^k=xa_m(a_mt^m)^k\in P_0$. So $f-a_mt^m\in P_1-P_0$. This is a contradiction by the inductive hypothesis with $(f,g):=(f-a_mt^m,g)$.
If $m\ge n\ge1$, then there exists $h\in A[It]$ such that $\deg(b_n^{m-n+1}f-hg)<n$ and $\deg h<m$. We have $b_n^{m-n+1}f-hg\in P_2$. So $b_n^{m-n+1}f-hg\in P_1$ by the inductive hypothesis with $(f,g):=(f,b_n^{m-n+1}f-hg)$. So $b_n^{m-n+1}f-hg\in P_0$ by the inductive hypothesis with $(f,g):=(b_n^{m-n+1}f-hg,g)$. So $hg\in P_1$. So $h\in P_1$. So $h\in P_0$ by the inductive hypothesis with $(f,g):=(h,g)$. So $b_n^{m-n+1}f\in P_0$. So $b_n\in P_0$. Since $\dim A=0$, there exist $k\ge0$ and $x\in A$ such that $b_n^k=xb_n^{k+1}$. So $(b_nt^n)^k=xb_n(b_nt^n)^k\in P_0$. So $g-b_nt^n\in P_2-P_1$. This is a contradiction by the inductive hypothesis with $(f,g):=(f,g-b_nt^n)$.



I think you should use different letters for the Krull dimension of $A$ and the degree of $g$.

Since you mention Seidenberg's paper, I imagine you are interested in the non-Noetherian case. However, when $A$ is Noetherian, $\dim A \le \dim A[It] \le \dim A + 1$, with equality on the left $I$ is contained in a minimal prime of maximal dimension ($\dim A/\mathfrak{p}  = \dim A$) and equality on the right if $I$ is not contained in such a prime. This is Swanson-Huneke, "Integral Closure of Ideals, Rings, and Modules", Theorem 5.1.4. They do not mention the non-Noetherian case in that subsection.
